# Function that Converts Missing Values (Char) to a Default Value

Tags: r

The function below works.  It converts missing values to some default value

```
convertNAsToDefault <- function(df, column, default) {
  df[[column]] <- as.character(df[[column]])
  df[is.na(df[[column]]), column] <- default
  df[[column]] <- as.factor(df[[column]])
  return (df)
}
```

This is how it might be used.

```
owners <- c('Becky', 'Alex', 'Jessica', 'Norm')
pets <- c('cat', 'dog', NA, 'dog')
d <- data.frame(owners, pets)
glimpse(d)

# Before: Jessica <NA>
convertNAsToDefault(d, 'pets', 'unknown')
# After:  Jessica unknown
```

I am wondering if there are ways to have written the function convertNAsToDefault() more elegantly or use an existing package to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function not only converts missing value to a default value, but transforms the columns of your dataframe to factor variables.

for simply removing missing values you don't need a function just use a logical vector:

```
d[is.na(d)] <- "unknown"
```

Of course, if "d$pets" already is a factor variable you first have to define a new level "unknown"

```
levels(d$pets) = c(levels(d$pets), "unknown")
```

Comment: This is much simpler.  Thank you, MarkusN

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `ifelse` function instead for some dataset df and variable, x:

```
as.factor(ifelse(is.na(df$x), "unknown", as.character(x)))
```

To move through many variables, you can use sapply:

```
newdf <- data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) as.character(ifelse(is.na(df$x), 
                                                        "unknown", as.character(x)))))
```